# Mounting SD Card after Installing Raspbian on it

Tags: sd-card

I followed [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md) to install Raspbian on an SD card. Now, I want to access the SD card to modify a few files, before plugging the card into my RasPi. In the end, I ran something like,

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.zip of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

I'm running Kubuntu 15.04 and I just can't access the SD card. I tried to mount the SD card by writing

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0 /mnt/raspi-fs
```

which results into

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Running `dmesg | tail` gives

```
[  599.510979] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 1234
[  599.511303] mmcblk0: mmc0:1234 SA16G 14.4 GiB 
[  599.513857]  mmcblk0: unknown partition table
```

What am I supposed to do to mount the FS and access the root directory of my Pi?

Comment: OMG, I'm so sorry. Using unzip prior to dd might be a good idea.

Comment: That, and you might want to mount a specific partition (e.g. `/dev/mmcblk0p1`) instead of the entire SD card device (`/dev/mmcblk0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to unzip the file to produce an `img` to write to the card.

It is unlikely that the SD card would be `/dev/mmcblk0`. 
Paste the output of `df -h` as suggested in the guide.

Running `dd` risks overwriting your system.

Comment: It was correct. Everything went well after doing the nice unzip trick.